# Getting the value of ng-model input from controller angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get the value of my ng-model input to my controller. The input value has a value and not empty. 
Why this code is not working? It says undefined when you alert or console log. What did i missed? really appreciate your help. here is my code

input --> the value is 1

```
    <input type="text" name="idval" ng-model="Data.idval">
```

js

```
app.controller('Controller', function($scope, $http){

$scope.fetchvalue = function(){

  var id = $scope.Data.idval; // not working
  var id = $scope.idval; // even this one

  alert(id); // its undefined

    $http.post(
        "query.php", {
            'ID': id,
        }
    ).then(function(response) {

       console.log(response.data);

    });
}});
```

Comment: is your input value hardcoded?

Comment: wen is that `fetchvalue` called, and have you taken `Data` object?

Comment: check your controller name

Comment: paste your complete controller

Comment: wen the button is click, called the fetchvalue @Sravan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working solution for your code:

You need to declare an `object` and bind it to `ng-model`,

**`$scope.Data = {};`**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.Data = {};
 $scope.fetchvalue = function(){
    var id = $scope.Data.idval; // not working
    alert(id); // its undefined
 }   
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="idval" ng-model="Data.idval"> 
    <button ng-click="fetchvalue()">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>



</body>
</html>
```

[**Here is a working Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/FXMPGcnP7aIfq8IWCb9R?p=preview)

Comment: it works! i missed this code in my controller $scope.Data = {}; Thanks @Sravan

Comment: Glad to help you :).

Answer (score 0):

I understand,

see you defined `id` twice, first id get the value from `ng-model` which must be assigning `ng-model` value to `id` variable and you override `id` with **undefined** variable called `idval`.

You can either remove line `var id = $scope.idval;` or

modify `alert(id);` as `alert($scope.Data.idval)`

Comment: i declare only id twice for showing that both of two are not working. but when in operation only one id at a time. Thanks @Kishor Pawar.

Comment: aha ok. That's why we expect more actual code here in post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare it somewhere before you use it.

```
$scope.DATA = ""
var id = $scope.Data.idval;
```

Try this out